# ExtJs DatePicker Inside jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, extjs, datepicker

I've been fighting with this for some time now and I'm hoping someone here has run into a similar problem and solution.

**Background**

Our project is an ASP.NET MVC 4 site.  It uses both jQuery 1.11.3 and Sencha ExtJs 4.2.2.  One of the features I'm working on is a page that will call different partial views that have individual report parameters.  The partials are also used in their own respectable pages.  However, this feature dynamically loads the partial views via jQuery ajax and displayed inside of a jQuery dialog.  Some of the partial view are using the ExtJs Ext.Button with a menu of Ext.menu.DatePicker.  On their own respectable page the date pickers work perfectly fine.  However, when the partial is loaded inside of the jQuery dialog it causes the datepicker calendar to set the position incorrectly causing massive overflow in the dialog.

Markup & code for the date picker on the partial

```
<td width="35%" class="tr35_form_input_normal">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CutOff, new { @style = "float:left;" })
    <div id="datePickerButton" style="float:left;margin-top:-2px;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CutOff)
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BeginDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EndDate)
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
                Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    iconCls: 'x-form-date-trigger',
                    renderTo: 'datePickerButton',
                    handler: function () {
                        this.menu = new Ext.menu.DatePicker({
                            renderTo: 'datePickerButton',
                            autoShow: true,
                            handler: function (picker, date) {
                                $(cutOffDate).val(Ext.Date.format(date, 'n/j/Y')).change();
                            }
                        });

                        this.menu.picker.setMinDate(new Date($(hfBeginDate).val()));
                        this.menu.picker.setMaxDate(new Date($(hfEndDate).val()));
                        if (!isNaN(Date.parse($(cutOffDate).val()))) {
                            this.menu.picker.setValue(new Date($(cutOffDate).val()));
                        }
                    }
                });
</script>
```

**This is how it looks & works on it's own page.**
[image: This is how it looks on it's own page.]

**How the dialog looks before I click on the date picker button.**
[image: How the dialog looks before I click on the date picker button.]

**What's happening when I click the button.**
[image: What's happening when I click the button.]

I can see what's happening and have an idea on how to fix it by using the jQuery widget factory to use the _allowInteraction method, which I've done before to fix an issue with ExtJs grids and their filters inside of a jQuery dialog.  The problem though is, the DatePicker has not been created yet when I first click the button so there's no way I can find the element/component.

The other thing you'll notice how the jQuery dialog seems to overflow.  I've tried to set the overflow to hidden on all the underlying elements and no matter what it still repositions the inner form element at some negative position.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after some more playing around here's my solution and it's quite simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.override(Ext.menu.DatePicker, {
    initComponent: function(){
        this.callParent();
    },
    listeners: {
        show: function(){
            var el = $('#' + this.id);
            var dlg = $(el).parents('.ui-dialog');
            //Make sure we are dealing with a datepicker
            //inside of a jQuery dialog.
            if($(dlg).length > 0){
                $(dlg).find('div.x-css-shadow').remove()
                $(el).appendTo('body');
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```